# (bootstrap grid col-md-4) alignment not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, nebular

I have the following issue displaying a page on Chrome and wondering if you encountered it as well.. Have you faced the following inconsistencies and how did you mitigate them?

In Chrome, one of my Nebular HTML tabs([TabB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnymW.png)) is not left justified.

Although in [TabA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsnTt.png) , using the same code, elements are left justified.

In Firefox, [TabB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjjyb.png) as a completely different layout.

Also I noticed that whenever I change TabB bootstrap code let's say from col-md-4 to col-md-9, the alignment changes in Firefox but not in Chrome..I tried clearing Chrome cache and restart, still no luck.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance!!

```
<nb-card>
<nb-card-header>
        <input nbInput id="search" class="search-input" placeholder="Search" #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)">
</nb-card-header>
   
<nb-card-body>
    <nb-tabset fullWidth>
        <nb-tab tabTitle="TabA">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of list_of_detail">
                    <nb-card status="success" *ngIf="item.env == 'A'">
                        <nb-card-header> {{ item.host }}</nb-card-header>
                        <nb-card-body>
                            version: {{ item.version }}
                        </nb-card-body>
                        <nb-card-footer>{{ item.service }} | {{ item.region }}</nb-card-footer>
                    </nb-card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nb-tab>

        <nb-tab tabTitle="TabB">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of list_of_detail">
                    <nb-card status="danger" *ngIf="item.env == 'B'">
                        <nb-card-header> {{ item.host }}</nb-card-header>
                        <nb-card-body>
                            version: {{ item.version }}
                        </nb-card-body>
                        <nb-card-footer>{{ item.service }} | {{ item.region }}</nb-card-footer>
                    </nb-card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nb-tab>
```

....

Comment: i hope you know that the col-sm effected for small devices only , not in your computer screen|

Answer (score 0):

i hope you know that the col-sm effected for small devices only , not in your computer screen .|

At Bootstrap 4, you can drop the "xs-" indicator for the lowest breakpoint:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-2 col-sm-3">Something here</div>
<div class="col-10 col-sm-9">Something else here</div>
</div>
```

Part of the "mobile first" mentality.

**Uses..**

`.col-`    Extra small (this code is for extra small deive screen eg: small android devises)

`.col-sm-` Small     (this code is for small deive screen eg: latest smart phones)

`.col-md-` Medium    (this code is for medium size deive screen )

`.col-lg-` Large     (this code is for large size deive screen eg: Computer screen)

`.col-xl-` Extra Large  (this code is for extra large size deive screen eg: android tv or other big larger screen)

the Bootstrap `col` is mean how to display a content in different size of screens | you can set muliple class with `class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-2"`. and now this will show in differently in different devises....

if you cant creat it well, i recoment you to download Bootstrap themes from bootstrap's own website | or if you want to learn Bootstrap , i recoment you to [w3schools.com/bootstrap4](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/default.asp)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply :) I just edited my question title and code. I actually was referring to col-md-4. I tried switching it to col-sm-4 at some point to see if it made a difference. Thx for clarifying the use for sm! Still wondering why col-md-4 not working as expected in my case. Neither in Chrome nor Firefox.

Comment: i understand the problem -- see the answer below.....

Answer (score 0):

Please Verify your code is like this
Now updated the code -- you can view the difference now

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--bootstrap 4.0----> <!---this is importent--->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<style>
.border{
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
</style>
<body>



    <nb-card>
        <nb-card-header>
                <input nbInput id="search" class="search-input ml-3 mt-2 mb-2" placeholder="Search" #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)">
        </nb-card-header>
           
        <nb-card-body>
           
            <nb-tabset fullWidth>
                <nb-tab tabTitle="TabA"> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 p-2 m-5 border" *ngFor="let item of list_of_detail">
                            <nb-card status="success" *ngIf="item.env == 'A'"> 
                                <nb-card-header> {{ item.host }}</nb-card-header>
                                <nb-card-body>
                                    version: {{ item.version }}
                                </nb-card-body>
                                <nb-card-footer>{{ item.service }} | {{ item.region }}</nb-card-footer>
                            </nb-card>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nb-tab>
        
                <nb-tab tabTitle="TabB"> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 p-2 m-5 border" *ngFor="let item of list_of_detail">
                            <nb-card status="danger" *ngIf="item.env == 'B'">
                                <nb-card-header> {{ item.host }}</nb-card-header>
                                <nb-card-body>
                                    version: {{ item.version }}
                                </nb-card-body>
                                <nb-card-footer>{{ item.service }} | {{ item.region }}</nb-card-footer>
                            </nb-card>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nb-tab>







    <!-----Bootstrap--> <!---this is importent--->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!---this is importent--->
    
</body>
</html>
```

**you must add css file**

```
 <!---bootstrap 4.0----> <!---this is importent--->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**And the script is**

```
<!-----Bootstrap--> <!---this is importent--->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!---this is importent--->
```

**You will get the answer like**
[image: you can view the code like this..]

[**View image In Full Screen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXRz1.png)

Comment: the boostrap javascript and css is must to run col-sm-4

Comment: after you did this, your code will run properly || thanks

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately I added the CSS file and scripts code above and the left justify alignment is still not happening...

Comment: I just noticed I am getting a bunch of warning messages. Maybe these are the cause of my issue. ng "build" "--output-path=dist"  gives me a Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
WARNING: Nebular Theme: `nb-theme()` cannot find value for key `color-fg` for theme `default`

Comment: the problem is with your view only . it working well in all devices. if you want to see the difference add borders on <div> | after that you can see the difference

Comment: i will update my code . and copy and paste the code in to your html file

Comment: the bootstrap code col-md is not for alignment . its for resizing... i f you want to align left add css/style `float:left;`

Comment: or other bootstrap way is creat a `<div>` as `<div class="row"> <!--here is you can add multiple divs, and it will be still in a row, try it! --> </div>`

Comment: You are right, the problem seem to be local..using float-left I still have the issue on Chrome for MAC (no changes seem to take effect on that browser but not on Firefox anymore on MAC. Also just checked and it works well on Chrome on Windows.

Comment: ooh, may be you need to update firefox in Mac os. try to update to latest version!